# Go lang file upload not working on the server

Tags: docker, go, server, upload, base64

My go-language file upload program runs inside a Docker container and is flawlessly functional locally. However, when I host it, it doesn't upload on the first try but does so on the second, but when I put it on the server outside of a docker container, everything runs smoothly.

```
func UploadFile() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var body = settings.BodyContent{}

        if err := c.BindJSON(&body); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"message": "Internal error", "success": false})
            return
        }

        cdn, err := minio.New("cdn.hahu.jobs", &minio.Options{
            Creds:  credentials.NewStaticV4(settings.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY, settings.MINIO_SECRET_KEY, ""),
            Secure: true,
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Auth error :: ", err)
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                "message": err.Error(),
                "success": false,
            })
            return
        }

        if body.Input.Folder[len(body.Input.Folder)-1:] != "/" {
            body.Input.Folder = body.Input.Folder + "/"
        }

        body.Input.Folder = "bridges/" + body.Input.Folder

        urls := []string{}
        secure_urls := []string{}

        for i := 0; i < len(body.Input.Files); i++ {
            file := body.Input.Files[i]
            var decoded []byte
            var kind types.Type

            parts := strings.Split(file, ",")
            file = parts[len(parts)-1]

            if decoded, err = base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(file); err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "message": err.Error(),
                    "success": false,
                })
                return
            }

            if kind, err = filetype.Match(decoded); err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "message": err.Error(),
                    "success": false,
                })
                return
            }

            id := body.Input.Folder + randstr.Hex(50)

            // Set a timeout for the HTTP request
            ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
            defer cancel()

            // Create a buffer to hold the file contents
            buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

            // Copy the data from the request body to the buffer
            if _, err = io.Copy(buf, c.Request.Body); err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "message": err.Error(),
                    "success": false,
                })
                return
            }

            // Upload the file to the CDN
            _, err = cdn.PutObject(ctx, "public", id, bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()), -1, minio.PutObjectOptions{
                ContentType: kind.MIME.Value,
            })
            if err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
                    "message": err.Error(),
                    "success": false,
                })
                return
            }

            url := fmt.Sprintf("http://cdn.hahu.jobs/public/%s", id)
            secure_url := fmt.Sprintf("https://cdn.hahu.jobs/public/%s", id)
            urls = append(urls, url)
            secure_urls = append(secure_urls, secure_url)

            // Break out of the loop after processing one file
            break
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "urls":        &urls,
            "secure_urls": &secure_urls,
        })
    }
}
```

this is the method i used and the file upload takes files as base64 and upload it to minio server.

Comment: What goes wrong?  If the problem is specific to Docker, how are you building your program into an image and how are you launching the corresponding container?  Do you need all of this Go code to demonstrate the issue, or would a smaller extract suffice?

Comment: the thing is I don't specifically know where the bug is I guess it is memory issues on the server the container restarts while I encounter the error